# How to initialize one class from a library?

Tags: c#, reflection, class, assemblies

I have a few classes in the class library (separate assembly). I referenced it to my project and I want to initialize one specific class from that library. I know only its name. All of the classes implements one interface.
And here comes the problem.

My code so far:

```
using MyLibrary;
...
IMyInterface dll = Activator.CreateInstance("MyLibrary", "MyLibrary.NameOfClass") as IMyInterface;
```

But dll is always null.
Any ideas?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I remove reference to the library and rewrite that code to:

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load("MyLibrary");
Type type = a.GetType("MyLibrary.SKClass");
IMyInterface obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IMyInterface;
```

but obj is null.

If I checked library types with a.GetExportedTypes(), SKClass is there. So why is this code still returning null?

Comment: try without "as"
try "Activator.CreateInstance("MyLibrary", "NameOfClass")

Comment: without "as part" it throws an error whether a cast is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"full\path\to.dll");

var type = assembly.GetType("Full.Namespace.Type");

var object = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using this...?

Assembly a = Assembly.Load("ClassLibrary1");
Interface1 i = a.CreateInstance("ClassLibrary1.ClassName") as Interface1;

Is it necessary that you have to use Activator...?